# Java - Slick2d: Very low framerate

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

This problem is not mine, so I will need some time to provide details.

XY sets up the Java environment for Slick2d programming based on a tutorial video series. XY uses same code as the tutor, but tutor gets 800 FPS and XY gets 5. The application is working as it is supposed to, but it has a major FPS issue. XY uses Eclipse for compiling.

What is worth checking in such a situation?

Comment: Your question is vague and impossible to ansver in the current form. Use a profiler to find the bottle neck in the code. The one included in the JDK is called 'jvisualvm' and should be able to do everything you need for this task.

Comment: I am sorry but I have to disagree, this question is not impossible to answer. Nothing specific is known about this issue right now, I got to admit that. I never really expected an exact solution. I need help for troubleshooting, answers like "check your java version" are very welcome. Reducing the possibilites that could cause this issue is already a big step in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is the rendering method XY is using. I do not know about the intricacies of Slick2D rendering, but since it uses OpenGL I can say the difference in performance between rendering methods is huge. If possible, I would try to use display lists or vertex buffer objects. I this [this forum post](http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4672) would be helpful.